# Как гарантировать встроенность функции?

Tags: gcc, c, c++

Функция определяется как

```
inline void func() {
    // тело функции
}
```

Я заметил, что далеко не всегда функция действительно делается "inline". То есть, компилятор как-то сам решает, когда встраивать, а когда не встраивать.

Answer (score 5):

Дело в том, что `inline`, вообще-то, и не предназначено для встраивания функций. Его используют для того, чтобы функции в h-файлах объявлять.

«Заставить» компилятор встроить функцию, вообще-то, универсального способа нет, т.к. Стандарт окончательное решение оставляет на откуп компилятору.
Лично я не знаю способа заставить gcc. Для mc есть секретное ключевое слово `__forceinline`.

Answer (score 3):

Абсолютно согласен с @kirelagin, "заставить" компилятор сделать это довольно сложно. Можно скорее помочь ему в этом. Причем слово inline ни о чем не говорит. Более верный способ следовать нескольким правилам при создании процедур.

1. процедура должна быть маленькой (несколько строк примерно, но никто не сможет сказать сколько именно)
2. ее определение должно быть доступно (разумеется lib и dll исключаются) и достаточно близко (в смысле единиц трансляции) к месту использования
3. не должны использоваться указатели на эту процедуру
4. если процедура - метод (т.е. в определена в классе), то не должна быть виртуальной (но есть исключение, такая процедура тоже может стать встраиваемой если вызывается в конструкторе)
5. возможно еще что есть, что сейчас не помню :)

следуя этим нехитрым правилам и при включенной в компиляторе оптимизации есть хорошие шансы для того чтобы компилятор "встроил" такую процедуру

Answer (score 3):

В стандарте сказано так:

> A function declared with an inline
> function speciﬁer is an *inline*
> *function*. The function speciﬁer may
> appear more than once; the behavior is
> the same as if it appeared only once.
> Making a function an inline function
> suggests that calls to the function be
> as fast as possible. The extent to
> which such suggestions are effective
> is implementation-deﬁned.

Т.е. если будет быстрее не встраивать функцию, то компилятор имеет право так сделать.

Из документации по gcc:

> You can also direct GCC to try to
> integrate all “simple enough”
> functions into their callers with the
> option -finline-functions.

Попробуй использовать этот ключ. Для проверки, стала ли функция inline используй ключ -Winline, тогда компилятор тебе сообщит, какие функции преобразованы во встроенные

Comment: Это
"Making a function an inline function suggests that calls to the function be as fast as possible."
переводится как:
"Создание функции встроенной функции предполагает, что вызов функции будет максимально быстро".
Т.е. вызов функции будет заметно быстрее если она будет inline. Т.е. вы ничего нового не сказали и перевели не верно.

Comment: @IAZ, перечитайте абзац целиком. Там английским языком написано, что выбор способа ускорения вызова функции остаётся на откуп компилятора. То есть ключевое слово inline не гарантирует, что функция действительно будет *inline*. Можете открыть стандарт, параграф 6.7.4, и весь его перечитать, ссылка - http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf.

Comment: @saigono а я разве против? только вот в чем дело - об этом тут уже писали... Вы написали: "Т.е. если будет быстрее не встраивать функцию, то компилятор имеет право так сделать". Извините конечно но это бред. Как можно быстро или медленно встраивать функцию???

Comment: А разве __attribute__((always_inline)) не подойдет?

Comment: @Вован при этом атрибуте компилятор будет сообщать если не сможет встроить данную функцию. Т.е. другими словами все равно ничего не гарантирует, но зато вы будете знать что с функцией происходит :)

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от сложности функции и её размеров. И это зависит от компилятора. В MinGW вообще не получилось использовать встроенные функции, компилятор ругался на них.

Comment: Вероятно, ты не использовал ключи типа -std=c99 или -std=gnu99

Comment: @saigono правильно подметил — там фишка с поддержкой разных стандартов. Либо использовать ключи, либо заменить inline на __inline__.

Comment: как раз ключи использовал ведь в с89 нету inline. Но вот __inline__ не использовал ещё. Спасибо попробую :-)