# inline функции на Java, оптимизация небольших функций

Tags: inline, java

Можно ли на Java определить встроенные функции?
Есть ли другие способы оптимизации часто вызываемых небольших методов класса?
Аналогичный вопрос для C/C++: [Как гарантировать встроенность функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2427/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096361/are-there-inline-functions-in-java)

Ниже примерно отвечали также как и я. Нельзя.
 1. Оптимизация жестокая - переписать на С++ с JNI, но не факт, что получится быстрее в современных JDK.
 2. Определять методы как static.

> No, there is no inline funtion in java. Yes, you can use a public static method anywhere in the code when placed in a public class. The java compiler may do inline expansion on a static or final method, but that is not garanteed.
>   Typically such code optimizations are done by the compiler in combination with the JVM/JIT/HotSpot for code segments used very often. Also other optimization concepts like register declaration of parameters are not known in java.
>   Optimizations cannot be forced by declaration in java, but done by compiler and JIT. In many other languages these declarations are often only compiler hints (you can declare more register parameters than the processor has, the rest is ignored).
>   Declaring java methods static, final or private are also hints for the compiler. You should use it, but no garantees. Java performance is dynamic, not static. First call to a system is always slow because of class loading. Next calls are faster, but depending on memory and runtime the most common calls are optimized whithin the running system, so a server may become more fast during runtime!

Answer (score 0):

Обычно компилятор сам делает функцию inline, если оно будет эффективно. Явное написание inline будет примерно таким
 - Добрый день, товарищь, компилятор! Мне кажется эту функцию лучше сделать inline? Что скажете?

Comment: В формулировке вопроса это и имелось ввиду: как на java порекомендовать компилятору сделать эту функцию inline?

Comment: Никак, основная оптимизация в Java происходит уже в процессе выполнения программы - JVM следит за ходом выполнения Java-кода (частота, "тяжесть" вызовов и проч.) и в процессе компиляции в родной для платформы код оптимизирует его соответственно, в том числе может проводить инлайны, если считает нужным. Кстати, именно благодаря таким вот оптимизациям Java-программы в некоторых случаях способны обгонять по скорости программы на C.